# PHP - Remove query string from font URLs

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, query-string

I have this string (sample) in a PHP variable:

```
@font-face {  
    src: url('../some-font.eot?v=4.6.3');
}
```

I need to search by **.eot?** on every line. If found, do a replace that results in:

```
@font-face {      
    src: url('../some-font.eot');
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight-forward using the `\Q...\E` sequence:

```
\Q.eot?\E[^'")]+
```

Replace this with `.eot` and see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/RA0JUr/2). The `\Q...\E` sequence treats all characters inside as plain literals so no escaping is needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jan, your solution works as intended too. Do you have a way to replace even when there isn't single or double quotes? Sample: url(../some-font.eot?v=4.6.3);

Comment: @EduardoSR: Of course, updated the demo - just add another `)` in the character class.

Answer (score 2):

Search for the string and then everything that is not your closing encapsulation character(s).

```
eot\?[^'"]+
```

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/SEPPHc/1/

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/761197

PHP:

```
$string = "@font-face {  
    src: url('../some-font.eot?v=4.6.3');
}";
echo preg_replace('/eot\?[^\'"]+/', 'eot', $string);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris, it works properly. Do you have a way to replace even when there isn't single or double quotes? Sample: url(../some-font.eot?v=4.6.3);

Comment: @EduardoSR What is consistent, always ends with `)`? Maybe https://regex101.com/r/SEPPHc/2/

Comment: Yes, always. The strings can be: `url('../some-font.eot?v=4.6.3');` or `url("../some-font.eot?v=4.6.3")` or `url(../some-font.eot?v=4.6.3)`

Comment: And I can do a second preg_replace, no need to be a unique regex, since your first solution matches both double and single quotes.

Comment: I tested SEPPHc/2 without quotes, it's removing the closing parentheses.. and if I have quotes, it removes the closing quote and closing parentheses.

Comment: @EduardoSR Jan's solution of adding the `)` in the character class will work.

Comment: Yes, it does... Thank you too Chris.

Comment: @chris85: +1 Compensating for the "stolen" accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a broad regular expression here (it will match pretty much anything up to the first `?`) but this should give you a starting point for the paths:

```
echo preg_replace("/^([^?]+).*/", "$1", "../some-font.eot?v=4.6.3");
```

Prints:

> ../some-font.eot

You'll want to remove the anchor and add some context for searching in the whole file, e.g using a positive lookbehind.

```
echo preg_replace("/(?<=src: url\(')([^?]+)[^']*?/", "$1", "src: url('../some-font.eot?v=4.6.3');");
```

Prints:

> src: url('../some-font.eot');

The lookbehind will ensure you only end up replacing the URLs you care about (e.g. it won't touch comments, `content` properties etc).